# How to use wscript.shell to ALT+Tab?

Tags: powershell, windows-scripting, comobject, wscript.shell

Is it possible to use `wscript.shell` to send an ALT+TAB ?

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.SendKeys('\t')
```

Comment: Question has been asked before. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370943/in-wsh-how-can-i-parse-multiple-key-presses-like-alt-ctrl-del

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send) instead.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('%{TAB}')
```

Not sure why but wscript.shell doesnt't work with %{TAB}.

Answer (score 0):

It is because it does not need use the % or use the \t.

Example:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "notepad", 9 

' Give Notepad time to load
WScript.Sleep 500 

Dim Msg: Msg = "Hello, World!"

' Type in One Character at a time
For i = 1 To Len(Msg)
    WScript.Sleep 200
    WshShell.SendKeys Mid(Msg, i, 1)
Next

WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WshShell.SendKeys "^{HOME}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
```

But since we all love PowerShell here, then what StephenP gave you is the PowerShell way to do this.